# BigQuery Stored Procedure SQL%RowFound

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

How do I check if SQL statement within stored procedure returned one or more rows successfully. Following is my stored procedure where I am checking if a particular table has duplicates. I am not sure how to write IF statement within stored procedure

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE, cols STRING,OUT found_duplicates STRING) 
BEGIN DECLARE sql STRING; 
set sql ='Select date,'||cols||','||'count(1) from '||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| ' where date=\''||date_id || '\' GROUP BY date,'||cols||'HAVING COUNT(*)>1'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SQL); 

if SQL%ROWSFOUND THEN
   found_duplicates ='Y'
ELSE 
   found_duplicates='N'
END;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to write the sql as:

```sql
DECLARE rowsFound BOOL;

set sql ='Select count(*) > 0 from '||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| ' where date=@date_id GROUP BY date,'||cols; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SQL) INTO rowsFound USING date_id AS date_id;
```

Note that date_id is also passed in as a parameter @date_id, this is always recommended.

You can also find more about `INTO` and `USING` for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE from [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).

You should also adjust the sql to make sure it only spits out 1 row to make `INTO` work.

Update: in case you need to capture more than one row

```sql
DECLARE rowsFound ARRAY<BOOL>;

SET sql ='Select <some_array>'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SQL) INTO rowsFound;
```

Comment: Hi , If the query returns more than one row, what variable I should use to catch all the results ?

Comment: added an example to my answer